# Insert inner arrays in JSON-encoded array to csv-file with php

Tags: php, arrays, json, csv

I have values from form that stored in DB with     `json_encode()` and I need to insert then these values into `.csv` file.
Here's my code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","db_pass","table_name");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT message FROM online_survey");
$sql->execute();
$array = [];
foreach ($sql->get_result() as $row){
    $array[] = json_decode($row['message'], true);
}
if (!$sql) {
    die(mysqli_error($con));
}

$fp = fopen('/path/to/file.csv', 'w');

foreach($array as $key) {
    fputcsv($fp, $key);
}

fclose($fp);
```

And in this file I am getting all values from this form except Arrays.
For example:

`Cell 1    Cell2      Cell3    Cell4      Cell5    Cell6     Cell7
OrgName    Country    City     Position            Scope     Array`

What I need is to get this:

```
Array
(
[organization_name] => orgName
[organisation_country] => Country
[organisation_city] => City
[organization_position] => position
[other_1_4_text] => 
[organisation_scope] => Local
[activity_areas] => Public finance management, Democratic participation and civil society, Urban development and management, Anti-corruption organisations and institutions, Children and youth
)
```

Instead of this:

```
Array
(
[organization_name] => orgName
[organisation_country] => Country
[organisation_city] => City
[organization_position] => position
[other_1_4_text] => 
[organisation_scope] => Local
[activity_areas] => Array
    (
        [0] => Public finance management
        [1] => Democratic participation and civil society
        [2] => Urban development and management
        [3] => Anti-corruption organisations and institutions
        [4] => Children and youth
    )
...
)
```

If you need some more information please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: On second `foreach` You can dump the var `var_dump( $key )` to check what is going on.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz updated!

Comment: Check is_array on the key and use print_r(key,true) to return it.

Comment: @Paul returned 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to implode the arrays:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b9f1cfe88ba659af30fc0d5a88f190c46f828a65))

```
$array=[
    'organization_name'=>'orgName',
    '[organisation_country'=>'Country',
    'organisation_city'=>'City',
    'organization_position'=>'position',
    'other_1_4_text'=>'', 
    'organisation_scope'=>'Local',
    'activity_areas'=>[
        'Public finance management',
        'Democratic participation and civil society',
        'Urban development and management',
        'Anti-corruption organisations and institutions',
        'Children and youth'
    ]
];

foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    if(is_array($v)){
        $v=implode(', ',$v);
    }
    $result[$k]=$v;
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'organization_name' => 'orgName',
  'organisation_country' => 'Country',
  'organisation_city' => 'City',
  'organization_position' => 'position',
  'other_1_4_text' => '',
  'organisation_scope' => 'Local',
  'activity_areas' => 'Public finance management,Democratic participation and civil society,Urban development and management,Anti-corruption organisations and institutions,Children and youth',
)
```

---

Edit:  It would be better to make this modification when you are looping through the db resultset...

```
$v=json_decode($row['message'],true);
$array[]=is_array($v)?implode(', ',$v):$v;
```